# MySql database INSERT operation works on hard disk(localhost) but not when hosted on the Internet

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I have a INSERT operation in my website which works like this.

1. On index.html file when a button is pressed a javascript function is called.
2. In the javascript function AJAX is used to send the request to the php file with necessary parameters
3. The php file accesses the database inserts data.

For your reference here is the code for the above tasks.

2.Javascript function

```
function grandFinale()
{
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","insert.php?q=&name=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('name').value) + "&txtScore1=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('txtScore1').innerHTML),true);
xmlhttp.send();
document.location.reload();

}
```

1.HTML button

```
<p id="txtScore1" align="center" style="color: #cc6699; font-size: 18px; "></p>
<label class="control-label" for="input01">Name</label>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript:grandFinale()" >Submit My Score</a>
```

3.PHP Script

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("host","uname","pword");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("dbname", $con) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $sql="INSERT INTO 'masterTable' ('Name', 'Score') VALUES ('{$_GET['name']}','{$_GET['txtScore1']}')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Things work fine when I try locally on harddisk but after  I host it on 000webhost.com the INSERT doesnt work. Can you suggest where I went wrong?

Comment: And the error you get is? Also, big SQL injection flaw. Sanitize user input!

Comment: Make sure your parameters for DB access are configured correctly for the host. Also please note that you shouldn't use the mysql_* functions for new applications as they are deprecated, and note that your application is completely vulnerable to SQL injection and you should use PDO parameterized queries to prevent this.

Comment: you have permission to insert data in server database.Check once?

Comment: If you haven't checked with your host's documentation and gotten a (presumably similar) direct example working, then there is no way we can help without getting `Too Localized`. You need to focus first on getting a test page working on your site's database, vis a vis your host's docs.

Comment: It should be a permissions issue. When I issue this command on SQL grant usage on . to 'uname'@'mysql6.000webhost.com' identified by 'password'; I get the following error. "#1045 - Access denied for user 'uname'@'localhost' (using password: YES) "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first check to see if the user you have set up for the database (uname) on 000webhost.com has INSERT privileges.

Comment: It should be a permissions issue. When I issue this command on SQL grant usage on *.* to 'uname'@'mysql6.000webhost.com' identified by 'password';  I get the following error. "#1045 - Access denied for user 'uname'@'localhost' (using password: YES) "

Comment: If I were you, I would add a new user under the Privileges tab (does your host have PHPMyAdmin?)  Then either select 'Grant all privileges on database "dbname"' or under Global privileges, be sure to at least check the "INSERT" box to verify that the new user has insert privileges.

Comment: It doesn't have a privileges tab. When I googled why it says it is disabled by default. They have suggested to login to phpmyadmin as root. I can't do that and it gives the error #1045. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How frustrating...maybe it's time to find a new host? ;)

Comment: suggestion.. pls? (a free one)

Comment: Not sure about free hosting, sorry.